# Custom Form Elements Styling

Tags: html, css, select, file-upload

I want to make some custom form elements. Which is the best library to use to make custom form elements ?

Mainly i am looking at File upload and Select Box.

The rest of the set i can style it in CSS3.

Comment: How do you mean custom form elements? Do you mean custom style, or are you trying to create a new type of element?

Comment: some of elements can be customize but some of not, I you want to customize all element then it's not possible without using JS, use js for some elements customization by googling :)

Comment: @Chandrakant i dont mind using js :D

Comment: There is no such singe web or space to get all element get styled, search around google for specific element, defiantly you will get best luck

Comment: @Harsha off-topic, harshamv.com and your startups radar aren't working

Comment: @Pekka shifting the server. Will up in a few days. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Choose-file element]

**Harsha bhai try making your own design, it will be a good learning experience, because it is easy**

You just have to understand few tricks (like for the choose-file element that you see),
these tricks just involve overlaying the non-stylable elements with divs that you create.

Use jquery/css for quikly learning how to position these divs on top of non-stylable elements, once this is done it will be fairly same across all browsers, but there is a slight difference like for the choose file element. I have given the necessary html,jquery that I use, if you have any doubt you can ask another question.

```
 $(function(){
  $('div#input_file_outer input[type=file]').change(function(e){
    $('div.file_name').html($('div#input_file_outer input[type=file]').val()); });
    $('div#input_file_outer input[type=file]').css({'cursor':'pointer'});

    if($.browser.opera) {
      $('div.file_name').css({'float':'left'});
      $('span.input_file_label').css({'float':'right','cursor':'pointer'});
    }
    if(!$.browser.opera) {
      $('span.input_file_label').css({'left':'-4px'});
    }
    $("div.input_file_cover,div#input_file_outer").css( { 'width':$("input.upload_file").outerWidth()+9+'px', 'height':$("input.upload_file").outerHeight()+2+'px', 'cursor':'pointer' });
    $("div.file_name,span.input_file_label").css( { 'height':$("input.upload_file").outerHeight()+'px', 'cursor':'pointer' });
  });

<input type="file" name="photograph" class="upload_file" title="Upload your jpeg/jpg photographs" style="cursor: pointer; ">

<div class="input_file_cover" style="width: 249px; height: 23px; cursor: pointer; ">
  <span class="input_file_label" style="left: -4px; height: 21px; cursor: pointer; ">
    Choose File
  </span>
  <div class="file_name" style="height: 21px; cursor: pointer; ">
    File name
  </div>
</div>
```

Sorry for typos, I have to rush

Comment: can you provide me more information regarding the same. do u have a demo some where with the styles/images

Comment: that yellow stuff is the background of the page, the grey color is the background color of the div that is placed on top of the upload button, remember to work very slowly with this, it will help you to learn jquery/javascript+css

Comment: and remember before start working try altering the opacity of web forms like upload then slowly start moving divs (added near form buttons) closer and because of reduced opacity of buttons you'll see buttons and divs

Answer (score 2):

you should try foundation css front-end framework 
Should do the trick for you
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/forms.php

Answer (score 1):

If you know your way around Jquery, that is the best way to create custom elements.

For custom select buttons I'd suggest using the Jquery library [customSelect](http://rixth.github.com/customSelect/). It lets you create select elements with a variety of things like text boxes inside of the select, radials, etc.

If you want a prebuilt fancy looking file upload with a progress bar, I'd suggest using [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/)